# Name of sci fi book series

Tags: story-identification, books

Anyone know the name/publisher of a series of sci fi novels that were composed of short stories around the main theme of man fighting a war against aggressive weasel like warriors. The story unfolded that an intelligent race were using these beings as mercenaries against the human race. Think there were centaurs as well at one point.

Answer (score 5):

"The Fleet" shared universe series by David Drake has weasel like Khalia race as the other side.